# jQuery - hover is triggered even though it shouldn't be

Tags: jquery, click, hover, slidetoggle

I have a simple jQuery drop down like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZVb7/1213/

What I want to achieve is, if the "More" button is hovered, the drop down menu will slideDown, and if the cursor leaves the "More" or the drop down, it will slideUp.

It works, however, if I add another event so that when any of the drop down is clicked, the whole drop down menu should slideUp, it doens't work. For some reason it also trigger the "hover" effect to make the drop down menu keep flashing.

html:

```
<div id="table">
<div class="container">
                        <a href="#" class="smallRedButton manage">More</a>
                        <div class="hidden list">
                            <ul>
                                <li>1</li>
                                <li>2</li>
                                <li>3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#table').on('hover', '.container', function(event) {
        console.log('hover');
        $(this).find('div').slideToggle(100);
            event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#table').on('click', '.container li', function(event) {
         $(this).parents(".list").slideUp('slow').show();

    });
})();
```

Comment: Please include the representative HTML and jQuery/JavaScript in your question. Don't circumvent the reported error by pretending your link is code.

Comment: all codes are in the jsfiddle.net I thought it will be much easier to see it then putting the code here

Comment: @Josh that does make it easier, but it's still required to be in your question just in case jsfiddle is unavailable. (which does happen occasionally).

Comment: okay I see next time I'll include the code here.

Comment: Note, the 'hover' pseudo event has been removed in recent versions of jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes It was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: later on I'll change it to mouseenter mouseleave. But still doesn't explain why it doesn't work in jquery 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that is what you want: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NvSff/2)

```
$(function() {
    $('#table').on('mouseover', '.manage', function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').slideDown('slow');
    }).on('mouseleave', '.container', function(event) {
        $(this).find('div').slideUp('slow');
    });

    $('#table').on('click', '.container li', function() {
        $(this).parents(".list").slideUp('slow').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do a pure css solution:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nGqsQ/1/

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
   <a href="#" class="handle">More</a>
   <div class="dropdown">
       <ul>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-container {
    width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown:hover,
.dropdown-container .handle:hover + .dropdown {
    max-height: 200px;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown ul {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown ul li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #0061a7;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0061a7;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

EDIT: the `dropdown-container` is optional, but I like wrapping stuff up to group them

EDIT2: Forgot to explain it...
The main part is:

```
.dropdown-container .dropdown {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.4s;
}

.dropdown-container .dropdown:hover,
.dropdown-container .handle:hover + .dropdown {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Here, `.dropdown` is set to `max-height: 0` by default, so it will not display on screen.

Then if you hover over the `.handle`, the rule `.handle:hover + .dropdown` will match and set `max-height: 200px`, you can change that to anything you want as long as it's larger than the actual height (exact value is preferred for a better looking animation). And if you change to hover over the `.dropdown` the rule `.dropdown-container .dropdown:hover` will be in effect.

Voila.

Comment: I don't want any workaround solution, I want to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because when it slides up, a mouseout event was triggered, then it expands and a mouseover event triggers....etc. And then why it just freaks out afterwards, I really don't want to know <_< But using a `event.preventDefault()` in the hover event probably isn't such a good hack in the first place. Which is why I would rewrite the whole thing completely...

Comment: i put the console.log on both hover and click. when the click calles the slideup, it doesn't trigger the hover console.log